# BlackBerry OutOfMemoryError

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError.   How do I solve this?

> Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Can you please 1st a have look at answers to your previous questions again and accept some of them.

Comment: In most cases, it indicates *memory leak* . Use tool such as jconsole to find the cause.

Comment: *"Please Give Me The Solution Please..."* - if you want to encourage people to help you, do the right thing and accept some answers to previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either increase the available heap space (with the Java `-Xmx` flag) or use less memory in your application.

I'd recommend that you try to use less memory. There are plenty of good profiling tools out there that you can use to discover where your code uses a lot of memory. It's also worth checking that you are not misusing any `HashMap`s or `ObjectOutputStream`s. Those two classes are notorious for soaking up memory if not used properly.